# mlx4 VF PF responsibilities - Query Mellanox

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I was going through the Mellanox driver (mlx4) and then I had difficulty understanding which portion of code corresponds to the one executed by the PF(Physical Function Driver) and which portion of code by (Virtual Function Driver) in the SRIOV mode.

My confusion is because, I was of the understanding that the QPs, CQs (and their creation, state mgmt commands) etc are to be performed by the virtual function driver(VF driver).

And the role of the physical function driver(PF driver) is to just take care of the resource_tracker.c and ICM allocation.

But of late, I think I may have understood wrong. This is because there is code that is specifically executed when mlx4_is_master is true/false( indicating PF or VF).

And then, there is code which is not surrounded by this test, which indicates it is executed in both cases(PF driver as well as VF driver).

Is my understanding correct? If yes, then are the QPs, CQs and ethernet tx, rx related functionality is executed both by master and slave?

Is there any way we can clearly separate the files that are used by PF vs the files that are used by VF in the (drivers/net/ethernet/mlx4 sub-directory)?

I would be really thankful and really appreciate all the help/clarification I can get in understanding this.

Thank you so much.

Best Regards,
Bob

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, this question was also posted and answered here: 
http://linux-pci.vger.kernel.narkive.com/mxQuEb2w/mlx4-query-regarding-pf-vf-functionality-division